# Oracle ODAC 18c installer doesn't work - screen flashes briefly

Tags: oracle, odac

I am having an issue running the installer.  I downloaded the ODAC 18c zip from Oracle.  Unzipped to folder "C:\ODAC Installer".   When I click on setup.exe, a window comes up briefly, then nothing happens.

I also tried running setup.exe from a command prompt, and had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Just documenting this in case someone runs into this frustrating error.

The issue was due to the space in the folder name for my install folder above.   I used my phone to take a video of the window popping up, then went through the video frame by frame.   I saw a reference to "C:\ODAC", which is not my install folder.

I renamed my folder to C:\ODACInstaller (no space), and the setup wizard starts up.

Comment: Open a command line window (`cmd.exe`) and start setup.exe from there. Would be more professional than taking a video with your smartphone.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I did try that and the behavior is exactly the same.  A separate window comes up briefly and then disappears.